# Is there any way to add "stars" to Spotify?

Tags: spotify

iTunes offers users the ability to give songs and albums up to 5 "stars." But Spotify only offers single stars. This makes it difficult to sort tracks and impossible to "dog ear" albums without throwing all contents into the "Starred" bin.

Is there any way to add more stars to Spotify's interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a feature that is currently available, although it has been asked for by lots of people. [Here is the most popular version of the question within Get Satisfaction](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/rating_songs_better_recommendations_statistics). Add your name to list to help it get more attention.